# Django templates iterate model fields with indices

Tags: django, templates

I have the follow model:

```
class UserProfile(...):
    ...
    photo1 = models.URLField()
    photo2 = models.URLField()
    photo3 = models.URLField()
    photo4 = models.URLField()
    photo5 = models.URLField()
```

And in the Create/Update template, I have to write five copies of the following `div` for `file1` to `file5`:

```
<div>  
  Photo 1:
  {% if userProfileForm.instance.file1 %}
    <a href="{{ userProfileForm.instance.file1 }}" target=_blank>View</a>
  {% endif %}
  <input type=file name=file1>
  {% if userProfileForm.instance.file1 %}
    <a href="{% url 'account:deletePhoto' userProfileForm.instance.id %}">Delete</a>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Is there a way to iterate field `file<i>`?

```
{% for i in '12345' %}
  <div>
    Photo {{ forloop.counter }}:

    ...

  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: may be someone help you to create a crutch to resolve your issue, but IMHO best way is create related model with `photo` and `sequence` fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in django you have [_meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/). So I think this solves your problem if you use get_fields method (and maybe you will filter desired fields out).

hope it helps.

**update with example**

let me show how you should solve your problem:

```
desired_fields = []
for field in UserProfile._meta.get_fields()
  if "photo" in field.name:
    desired_fields.append(field.name)
context.update(fields=desired_fields)  # pass it in the context
```

at this point you have your desired fields which should be used with for loop in the template. And one more thing, you would need to add some template tag to get real field from string representation:

```
# custom template tag
def from_string_to_field(instance, field_str):
  return getattr(instance, field_str, None)
```

and in the template code will look like this

```
{% for field in fields %}
  {{userProfileForm.instance|from_string_to_field:"field"}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But how do I get the field in the template? `{{ userProfileForm.instance.get_fields }}` does not work.

Comment: please view the updated answer, hope it gives you more details and full path how you should use _meta API.